# How to fix HDMI Audio on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (update broke it)

Tags: 14.04, sound, hdmi

i know this question is often asked and has  a lot of solutions, but none worked for me. After running the package-update from GUI i was watching movie with xbmc and everything worked (and has worked for months). Next day i power on and sound is gone. I had this problem once and if i remember correctly i was able to fix it with adding the the daily-alsa repository and installing the oem package (or i deinstalled pulseaudio/alsa and reinstalled, not sure). I tried everything i found on the web and nothing works. I know some stuff about Linux, but i'm stuck here - please help, this is my HTPC and having no sound is a true PITA :(

System: Intel NUC-Kit D34010WYK (i3)
OS: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

i tried:

- deinstalled/reinstalled alsa-base, alsa-utils, pulseaudio,
  linux-sound-base, oem-audio-hda-daily-dkms
- sudo alsa force-reload

things worth to mention (maybe?)

- i found no .asoundrc nor do i have a ~/.pulse folder
- alsamixer shows one channel (s/pdif) and i cant change the volume on it
- pulseaudio cmd results in error:

`E: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: pa_pid_file_create() failed.`

I think i have the update-log which broke my audio:

```
Start-Date: 2015-09-08  23:20:20
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.60'
Install: linux-image-extra-3.13.0-63-generic:amd64 (3.13.0-63.103)
libplatform1:amd64 (1.0.10-1~trusty, automatic)
linux-image-3.13.0-63-generic:amd64 (3.13.0-63.103)
linux-headers-3.13.0-63-generic:amd64 (3.13.0-63.103)
libcec3:amd64 (3.0.1-1~trusty)
linux-signed-image-3.13.0-63-generic:amd64 (3.13.0-63.103)
linux-headers-3.13.0-63:amd64 (3.13.0-63.103)
Upgrade: bind9-host:amd64 (9.9.5.dfsg-3ubuntu0.2, 9.9.5.dfsg-3ubuntu0.5)
shim-signed:amd64 (1.6+0.4-0ubuntu4, 1.9+0.8-0ubuntu2)
initscripts:amd64 (2.88dsf-41ubuntu6.1, 2.88dsf-41ubuntu6.2)
python3-problem-report:amd64 (2.14.1-0ubuntu3.11, 2.14.1-0ubuntu3.12)
oxideqt-codecs:amd64 (1.7.8-0ubuntu0.14.04.1, 1.8.4-0ubuntu0.14.04.2)
oem-audio-hda-daily-dkms:amd64 (0.201506190242~ubuntu14.04.1, 0.201509081346~ubuntu14.04.1)
liblwres90:amd64 (9.9.5.dfsg-3ubuntu0.2, 9.9.5.dfsg-3ubuntu0.5)
gir1.2-udisks-2.0:amd64 (2.1.3-1, 2.1.3-1ubuntu0.1)
apt:amd64 (1.0.1ubuntu2.8, 1.0.1ubuntu2.10)
hplip:amd64 (3.14.3-0ubuntu3.2, 3.14.3-0ubuntu3.4)
libfontembed1:amd64 (1.0.52-0ubuntu1.4, 1.0.52-0ubuntu1.5)
libasan0:amd64 (4.8.2-19ubuntu1, 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04)
libsystemd-login0:amd64 (204-5ubuntu20.12, 204-5ubuntu20.13)
linux-headers-generic:amd64 (3.13.0.55.62, 3.13.0.63.71)
libquadmath0:amd64 (4.8.2-19ubuntu1, 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04)
gcc-4.8-base:amd64 (4.8.2-19ubuntu1, 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04)
gcc-4.8-base:i386 (4.8.2-19ubuntu1, 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04)
grub-efi-amd64-bin:amd64 (2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1.2, 2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1.3)
gdisk:amd64 (0.8.8-1build1, 0.8.8-1ubuntu0.1)
libwmf0.2-7:amd64 (0.2.8.4-10.3ubuntu1, 0.2.8.4-10.3ubuntu1.14.04.1)
libpython2.7-stdlib:amd64 (2.7.6-8, 2.7.6-8ubuntu0.2)
libdns100:amd64 (9.9.5.dfsg-3ubuntu0.2, 9.9.5.dfsg-3ubuntu0.5)
python-samba:amd64 (4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.7, 4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.9)
libisccfg90:amd64 (9.9.5.dfsg-3ubuntu0.2, 9.9.5.dfsg-3ubuntu0.5)
systemd-services:amd64 (204-5ubuntu20.12, 204-5ubuntu20.13)
grub-efi-amd64:amd64 (2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1.2, 2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1.3)
apt-transport-https:amd64 (1.0.1ubuntu2.8, 1.0.1ubuntu2.10)
python-pkg-resources:amd64 (3.3-1ubuntu1, 3.3-1ubuntu2)
isc-dhcp-common:amd64 (4.2.4-7ubuntu12.2, 4.2.4-7ubuntu12.3)
libbind9-90:amd64 (9.9.5.dfsg-3ubuntu0.2, 9.9.5.dfsg-3ubuntu0.5)
openjdk-6-jre-lib:amd64 (6b35-1.13.7-1ubuntu0.14.04.1, 6b36-1.13.8-0ubuntu1~14.04)
libsane-hpaio:amd64 (3.14.3-0ubuntu3.2, 3.14.3-0ubuntu3.4)
firefox-locale-en:amd64 (38.0+build3-0ubuntu0.14.04.1, 40.0.3+build1-0ubuntu0.14.04.1)
python3.4:amd64 (3.4.0-2ubuntu1, 3.4.0-2ubuntu1.1)
cpp-4.8:amd64 (4.8.2-19ubuntu1, 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04)
libgomp1:amd64 (4.8.2-19ubuntu1, 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04)
dkms:amd64 (2.2.0.3-1.1ubuntu5.14.04, 2.2.0.3-1.1ubuntu5.14.04.1)
xul-ext-ubufox:amd64 (3.0-0ubuntu0.14.04.1, 3.1-0ubuntu0.14.04.1)
libtsan0:amd64 (4.8.2-19ubuntu1, 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04)
libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common:amd64 (2.30.7-0ubuntu1, 2.30.7-0ubuntu1.1)
apt-utils:amd64 (1.0.1ubuntu2.8, 1.0.1ubuntu2.10)
iproute2:amd64 (3.12.0-2, 3.12.0-2ubuntu1)
udisks2:amd64 (2.1.3-1, 2.1.3-1ubuntu0.1)
thunderbird:amd64 (31.7.0+build1-0ubuntu0.14.04.1, 38.2.0+build1-0ubuntu0.14.04.1)
libhpmud0:amd64 (3.14.3-0ubuntu3.2, 3.14.3-0ubuntu3.4)
libtag1c2a:amd64 (1.9.1-2, 1.9.1-2.2~ppa~trusty)
ubuntu-drivers-common:amd64 (0.2.91.9, 0.2.91.11)
firefox:amd64 (38.0+build3-0ubuntu0.14.04.1, 40.0.3+build1-0ubuntu0.14.04.1)
mount:amd64 (2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20.4, 2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20.6)
icedtea-6-jre-cacao:amd64 (6b35-1.13.7-1ubuntu0.14.04.1, 6b36-1.13.8-0ubuntu1~14.04)
samba:amd64 (4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.7, 4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.9)
python3.4-minimal:amd64 (3.4.0-2ubuntu1, 3.4.0-2ubuntu1.1)
parted:amd64 (2.3-19ubuntu1, 2.3-19ubuntu1.14.04.1)
libsystemd-daemon0:amd64 (204-5ubuntu20.12, 204-5ubuntu20.13)
libgudev-1.0-0:amd64 (204-5ubuntu20.12, 204-5ubuntu20.13)
libgs9-common:amd64 (9.10~dfsg-0ubuntu10.2, 9.10~dfsg-0ubuntu10.4)
tzdata-java:amd64 (2015d-0ubuntu0.14.04, 2015f-0ubuntu0.14.04)
grub-common:amd64 (2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1.2, 2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1.3)
dh-python:amd64 (1.20140128-1ubuntu8, 1.20140128-1ubuntu8.2)
libwmf0.2-7-gtk:amd64 (0.2.8.4-10.3ubuntu1, 0.2.8.4-10.3ubuntu1.14.04.1)
libapparmor1:amd64 (2.8.95~2430-0ubuntu5.1, 2.8.95~2430-0ubuntu5.3)
libpython3.4-stdlib:amd64 (3.4.0-2ubuntu1, 3.4.0-2ubuntu1.1)
libpam-systemd:amd64 (204-5ubuntu20.12, 204-5ubuntu20.13)
python3-pkg-resources:amd64 (3.3-1ubuntu1, 3.3-1ubuntu2)
gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0:amd64 (2.30.7-0ubuntu1, 2.30.7-0ubuntu1.1)
python2.7:amd64 (2.7.6-8, 2.7.6-8ubuntu0.2)
openjdk-6-jre-headless:amd64 (6b35-1.13.7-1ubuntu0.14.04.1, 6b36-1.13.8-0ubuntu1~14.04)
flashplugin-installer:amd64 (11.2.202.466ubuntu0.14.04.1, 11.2.202.508ubuntu0.14.04.1)
python3-requests:amd64 (2.2.1-1ubuntu0.2, 2.2.1-1ubuntu0.3)
libapt-inst1.5:amd64 (1.0.1ubuntu2.8, 1.0.1ubuntu2.10)
libuuid1:amd64 (2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20.4, 2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20.6)
libnss3-1d:amd64 (3.17.4-0ubuntu0.14.04.1, 3.19.2-0ubuntu0.14.04.1)
libmount1:amd64 (2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20.4, 2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20.6)
libsnmp-base:amd64 (5.7.2~dfsg-8.1ubuntu3, 5.7.2~dfsg-8.1ubuntu3.1)
kodi:amd64 (14.2~git20150327.1058-final-0trusty, 15.1~git20150816.1137-final-0trusty)
libpython3.4:amd64 (3.4.0-2ubuntu1, 3.4.0-2ubuntu1.1)
dnsutils:amd64 (9.9.5.dfsg-3ubuntu0.2, 9.9.5.dfsg-3ubuntu0.5)
kodi-bin:amd64 (14.2~git20150327.1058-final-0trusty, 15.1~git20150816.1137-final-0trusty)
ssh-askpass-gnome:amd64 (6.6p1-2ubuntu2, 6.6p1-2ubuntu2.3)
udev:amd64 (204-5ubuntu20.12, 204-5ubuntu20.13)
base-files:amd64 (7.2ubuntu5.2, 7.2ubuntu5.3)
patch:amd64 (2.7.1-4ubuntu2, 2.7.1-4ubuntu2.3)
printer-driver-postscript-hp:amd64 (3.14.3-0ubuntu3.2, 3.14.3-0ubuntu3.4)
samba-dsdb-modules:amd64 (4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.7, 4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.9)
grub2-common:amd64 (2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1.2, 2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1.3)
bash-completion:amd64 (2.1-4, 2.1-4ubuntu0.1)
libatomic1:amd64 (4.8.2-19ubuntu1, 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04)
libnss3-nssdb:amd64 (3.17.4-0ubuntu0.14.04.1, 3.19.2-0ubuntu0.14.04.1)
ghostscript-x:amd64 (9.10~dfsg-0ubuntu10.2, 9.10~dfsg-0ubuntu10.4)
libsqlite3-0:amd64 (3.8.2-1ubuntu2, 3.8.2-1ubuntu2.1)
libpython3.4-minimal:amd64 (3.4.0-2ubuntu1, 3.4.0-2ubuntu1.1)
libunity-control-center1:amd64 (14.04.3+14.04.20140922-0ubuntu1, 14.04.3+14.04.20140922-0ubuntu1.1)
gir1.2-gudev-1.0:amd64 (204-5ubuntu20.12, 204-5ubuntu20.13)
samba-common-bin:amd64 (4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.7, 4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.9)
openjdk-6-jre:amd64 (6b35-1.13.7-1ubuntu0.14.04.1, 6b36-1.13.8-0ubuntu1~14.04)
cups-browsed:amd64 (1.0.52-0ubuntu1.4, 1.0.52-0ubuntu1.5)
libparted0debian1:amd64 (2.3-19ubuntu1, 2.3-19ubuntu1.14.04.1)
liboxideqtcore0:amd64 (1.7.8-0ubuntu0.14.04.1, 1.8.4-0ubuntu0.14.04.2)
libudev1:amd64 (204-5ubuntu20.12, 204-5ubuntu20.13)
libudev1:i386 (204-5ubuntu20.12, 204-5ubuntu20.13)
binutils:amd64 (2.24-5ubuntu3.1, 2.24-5ubuntu13)
linux-image-extra-3.13.0-55-generic:amd64 (3.13.0-55.92, 3.13.0-55.94)
cups-filters-core-drivers:amd64 (1.0.52-0ubuntu1.4, 1.0.52-0ubuntu1.5)
linux-headers-3.13.0-55:amd64 (3.13.0-55.92, 3.13.0-55.94)
linux-image-3.13.0-55-generic:amd64 (3.13.0-55.92, 3.13.0-55.94)
bsdutils:amd64 (2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20.4, 2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20.6)
libapparmor-perl:amd64 (2.8.95~2430-0ubuntu5.1, 2.8.95~2430-0ubuntu5.3)
linux-signed-generic:amd64 (3.13.0.55.62, 3.13.0.63.71)
grub-efi-amd64-signed:amd64 (1.34.3+2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1.2, 1.34.4+2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1.3)
samba-libs:amd64 (4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.7, 4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.9)
openssh-client:amd64 (6.6p1-2ubuntu2, 6.6p1-2ubuntu2.3)
libapt-pkg4.12:amd64 (1.0.1ubuntu2.8, 1.0.1ubuntu2.10)
efibootmgr:amd64 (0.5.4-7ubuntu1.1, 0.5.4-7ubuntu1.2)
uuid-runtime:amd64 (2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20.4, 2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20.6)
libgcc-4.8-dev:amd64 (4.8.2-19ubuntu1, 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04)
libpython2.7:amd64 (2.7.6-8, 2.7.6-8ubuntu0.2)
libpcre3-dev:amd64 (8.31-2ubuntu2, 8.31-2ubuntu2.1)
mysql-common:amd64 (5.5.43-0ubuntu0.14.04.1, 5.5.44-0ubuntu0.14.04.1)
python-six:amd64 (1.5.2-1, 1.5.2-1ubuntu1)
xbmc:amd64 (14.2~git20150327.1058-final-0trusty, 15.1~git20150816.1137-final-0trusty)
thunderbird-gnome-support:amd64 (31.7.0+build1-0ubuntu0.14.04.1, 38.2.0+build1-0ubuntu0.14.04.1)
libtag1-vanilla:amd64 (1.9.1-2, 1.9.1-2.2~ppa~trusty)
gcc-4.8:amd64 (4.8.2-19ubuntu1, 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04)
libsystemd-journal0:amd64 (204-5ubuntu20.12, 204-5ubuntu20.13)
isc-dhcp-client:amd64 (4.2.4-7ubuntu12.2, 4.2.4-7ubuntu12.3)
libnss3:amd64 (3.17.4-0ubuntu0.14.04.1, 3.19.2-0ubuntu0.14.04.1)
libmysqlclient18:amd64 (5.5.43-0ubuntu0.14.04.1, 5.5.44-0ubuntu0.14.04.1)
sysv-rc:amd64 (2.88dsf-41ubuntu6.1, 2.88dsf-41ubuntu6.2)
cups-filters:amd64 (1.0.52-0ubuntu1.4, 1.0.52-0ubuntu1.5)
unity-settings-daemon:amd64 (14.04.0+14.04.20140606-0ubuntu2, 14.04.0+14.04.20140606-0ubuntu3)
smbclient:amd64 (4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.7, 4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.9)
linux-headers-3.13.0-55-generic:amd64 (3.13.0-55.92, 3.13.0-55.94)
printer-driver-hpcups:amd64 (3.14.3-0ubuntu3.2, 3.14.3-0ubuntu3.4)
unity-control-center:amd64 (14.04.3+14.04.20140922-0ubuntu1, 14.04.3+14.04.20140922-0ubuntu1.1)
apport-gtk:amd64 (2.14.1-0ubuntu3.11, 2.14.1-0ubuntu3.12)
lightdm:amd64 (1.10.5-0ubuntu1, 1.10.5-0ubuntu1.1)
liboxideqtquick0:amd64 (1.7.8-0ubuntu0.14.04.1, 1.8.4-0ubuntu0.14.04.2)
passwd:amd64 (4.1.5.1-1ubuntu9, 4.1.5.1-1ubuntu9.1)
apport:amd64 (2.14.1-0ubuntu3.11, 2.14.1-0ubuntu3.12)
libgs9:amd64 (9.10~dfsg-0ubuntu10.2, 9.10~dfsg-0ubuntu10.4)
libpcrecpp0:amd64 (8.31-2ubuntu2, 8.31-2ubuntu2.1)
linux-signed-image-generic:amd64 (3.13.0.55.62, 3.13.0.63.71)
linux-firmware:amd64 (1.127.12, 1.127.15)
python-requests:amd64 (2.2.1-1ubuntu0.2, 2.2.1-1ubuntu0.3)
python2.7-minimal:amd64 (2.7.6-8, 2.7.6-8ubuntu0.2)
sysvinit-utils:amd64 (2.88dsf-41ubuntu6.1, 2.88dsf-41ubuntu6.2)
liboxideqt-qmlplugin:amd64 (1.7.8-0ubuntu0.14.04.1, 1.8.4-0ubuntu0.14.04.2)
libblkid1:amd64 (2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20.4, 2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20.6)
liblightdm-gobject-1-0:amd64 (1.10.5-0ubuntu1, 1.10.5-0ubuntu1.1)
login:amd64 (4.1.5.1-1ubuntu9, 4.1.5.1-1ubuntu9.1)
libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:amd64 (2.30.7-0ubuntu1, 2.30.7-0ubuntu1.1)
hplip-data:amd64 (3.14.3-0ubuntu3.2, 3.14.3-0ubuntu3.4)
libexpat1:amd64 (2.1.0-4ubuntu1, 2.1.0-4ubuntu1.1)
libexpat1:i386 (2.1.0-4ubuntu1, 2.1.0-4ubuntu1.1)
python3-apport:amd64 (2.14.1-0ubuntu3.11, 2.14.1-0ubuntu3.12)
apparmor:amd64 (2.8.95~2430-0ubuntu5.1, 2.8.95~2430-0ubuntu5.3)
tzdata:amd64 (2015d-0ubuntu0.14.04, 2015f-0ubuntu0.14.04)
libwbclient0:amd64 (4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.7, 4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.9)
samba-vfs-modules:amd64 (4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.7, 4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.9)
libvdpau1:amd64 (0.7-1, 0.7-1ubuntu0.1)
linux-libc-dev:amd64 (3.13.0-55.92, 3.13.0-63.103)
util-linux:amd64 (2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20.4, 2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20.6)
iproute:amd64 (3.12.0-2, 3.12.0-2ubuntu1)
ghostscript:amd64 (9.10~dfsg-0ubuntu10.2, 9.10~dfsg-0ubuntu10.4)
samba-common:amd64 (4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.7, 4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.9)
python3-six:amd64 (1.5.2-1, 1.5.2-1ubuntu1)
libstdc++6:amd64 (4.8.2-19ubuntu1, 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04)
libstdc++6:i386 (4.8.2-19ubuntu1, 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04)
libpcre3:amd64 (8.31-2ubuntu2, 8.31-2ubuntu2.1)
icedtea-6-jre-jamvm:amd64 (6b35-1.13.7-1ubuntu0.14.04.1, 6b36-1.13.8-0ubuntu1~14.04)
libudisks2-0:amd64 (2.1.3-1, 2.1.3-1ubuntu0.1)
libitm1:amd64 (4.8.2-19ubuntu1, 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04)
unattended-upgrades:amd64 (0.82.1ubuntu2.2, 0.82.1ubuntu2.3)
libsnmp30:amd64 (5.7.2~dfsg-8.1ubuntu3, 5.7.2~dfsg-8.1ubuntu3.1)
libpython2.7-minimal:amd64 (2.7.6-8, 2.7.6-8ubuntu0.2)
linux-signed-image-3.13.0-55-generic:amd64 (3.13.0-55.92, 3.13.0-55.94)
linux-image-generic:amd64 (3.13.0.55.62, 3.13.0.63.71)
irqbalance:amd64 (1.0.6-2ubuntu0.14.04.1, 1.0.6-2ubuntu0.14.04.2)
libisccc90:amd64 (9.9.5.dfsg-3ubuntu0.2, 9.9.5.dfsg-3ubuntu0.5)
shim:amd64 (0.4-0ubuntu4, 0.8-0ubuntu2)
libsmbclient:amd64 (4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.7, 4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.9)
libisc95:amd64 (9.9.5.dfsg-3ubuntu0.2, 9.9.5.dfsg-3ubuntu0.5)
linux-generic:amd64 (3.13.0.55.62, 3.13.0.63.71)
libcupsfilters1:amd64 (1.0.52-0ubuntu1.4, 1.0.52-0ubuntu1.5)
Remove: libcec2:amd64 (2.2.0-2~trusty)
End-Date: 2015-09-08  23:30:27
```

my guess its this:

```
oem-audio-hda-daily-dkms:amd64 (0.201506190242~ubuntu14.04.1, 0.201509081346~ubuntu14.04.1)
```

i tried to force version with synapdic package manager or even download old version manually but haven'T found it on the web :(

any help very much appreciated - i can provide any info you need (aplay -l etc, just tell me)
thx

Comment: just gathered some info, but problem persists - more info at: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2294268&p=13354163#post13354163

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest kernel update 3.13.0-63-generic was the source of the problems. Someone at ubuntuforums helped me (see comment for link).

Edit grub config:

```
# GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
# GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=20
```

Update grub in terminal:

```
sudo update-grub
```

then after reboot i selected another kernel in the advanced menu (for me it was 3.13.0-55, but according to forums 0-62 should also work)

Answer (score 0):

In alsamixer , press <kbd>F6</kbd> and select the second soundcard (if present)  .
Hopefully, this will provide more controls , so you can unmute    faders with <kbd>m</kbd> or increase level on some badly configured faders.